# Simple question on Giamarchi's book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, bosonization

I have trouble from Eq.(2.62) to Eq.(2.63) in Giamarchi's "Quantum Physics in One Dimension". The book says as follows, but I think that some terms are missing.
[image]

By straight computation of $\rho(r)\rho(0)$, I think there should be more terms, such as
$$ -\frac{1}{\pi} \nabla\phi(r) \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha}[e^{-i2\phi(0)}+h.c.]$$
and
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha}[e^{i2k_Fx}e^{-i2\phi(r)}+h.c.]\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\pi}\nabla\phi(0)\right).$$

Where are they?